# Rearranging Equations

Tags: exponential-function

How can I get from the first image to the second image? I've tried various ways but how does the exponential end up with a negative in front of it?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]]

Answer (score 2):

HINT: multiply numerator and denominator by $$e^{-2\sqrt{Cg}t}$$

Comment: your answer is eerily similar to mine, but you beat me by 30 seconds. well played ;)

Comment: but you get also your Points!

Comment: Of course! I got it thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Multiply the RHS by $$ \frac{e^{-2\sqrt{Cg}t}}{e^{-2\sqrt{Cg}t}} $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer too!